# Shipment Email Template issue Magento 2.3.1

Tags: email-templates, magento2.3.1, shipment

I am using Magento 2.3.1 CE.
My English is not perfect sorry.
**Admin > Marketing > Email Templates > Shipment Email Template**
When I click preview template, I see this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTracksCollection() on null in /var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml:1

I added a picture. https://prnt.sc/nyyeei

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can create a template file in your theme 
this core file :

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml
```

and add condition before this function

```
getTracksCollection
```

you can add condition like this

```
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order): ?>
```

So that issue will fixed for magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 4):

There must be some custom email template that must be using an older syntax (in file or in database)
Replace `{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}`
To {{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}

Answer (score 3):

**We had the same issue in Magento 2.3.3. I have fixed it in this way.**

*Created a template file in the custom theme: Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml*

```
<?php $_shipment = $block->getShipment() ?>
$_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order) : ?>
    <?php $trackCollection = $_order->getTracksCollection($_shipment->getId()) ?>
    <?php if ($trackCollection) : ?>
        <br />
        <table class="shipment-track">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shipped By')) ?></th>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Tracking Number')) ?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($trackCollection as $_item) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getTitle()) ?>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($this->helper('Magento\Shipping\Helper\Data')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_item)) ?>" target="_blank"> 
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?> 
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in Magento 2.2.8. The reason is, when you try to review mail template there is not available **order** object.

I have fixed it in this way.

Created a template file in the custom theme:
**Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_shipment = $block->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order): ?>
    <?php $trackCollection = $_order->getTracksCollection($_shipment->getId()) ?>
    <br />
    <table class="shipment-track">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Shipped By') ?></th>
            <th><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Tracking Number') ?></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if ($trackCollection): ?>
            <?php foreach ($trackCollection as $_item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getTitle()) ?>:</td>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```